# On the measure of nonconvexity (MNC)

Tags: banach-spaces, convexity, examples

I'm actually working on the measure of nonconvexity and its application. Especially, the  [Eisenfeld–Lakshmikantham MNC](https://rc.library.uta.edu/uta-ir/bitstream/handle/10106/2198/MathTechReport026.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) defined - in a Banach space - by:

$$\alpha(A)=\sup_{b\in\operatorname{conv}(A)} \inf_{a\in A}|| b-a \|<\infty $$
Alternatively, if $H(X, Y)$ denotes the Hausdorff distance between two subsets $X$ and $Y$,
$$\alpha(A)=H(A, \operatorname{conv}(A))$$

where $\operatorname{conv}(A)$ is the convex hull of $A$.

The interesting thing about the E-L MNC is that $\alpha(A)=0 \Longrightarrow \overline{A} \text{ is convex}.$

---

I'm looking for a sequence of **non-convex** sets $(A_n)_n\subset E$ - which somehow - verify a "contraction" condition, that is,
$$\alpha(A_{n+1})\leq \lambda\,\alpha(A_{n})\text{ where } \lambda \in (0,1).$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple problem and I am voting to close it. Take any non-convex set $A$ with $\alpha(A)<\infty$ and define $A_n=\lambda^n A$ (dilation with the factor $\lambda^n$. Then $\alpha(A_n)=\lambda^n\alpha(A)$, because the distances are scaling by that factor and hence $\alpha(A_{n+1})=\lambda \alpha(A_n)$.

Comment: This answers the actual question. I wouldn't be surprised if the intended question wanted all the sets $A_n$ to have the same convex hull, so that, as $n$ increases, you're gradually filling in the places where $A$ fails to be convex.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Even if we assume that the sets have the same convex hull, the question is stil trivial. Take a ball $B$ and define $A_n$ by removing a very small ball from $B$.